# Error of "cannot be applied to..." in enum string objects

Tags: java, enums

I've researched and fixed the formatting, created getters and setters and constructors, but it's still returning an error that I cannot apply my string objects. I apologize for how I word my question but I don't know how to clearly state my problem as I don't understand it well enough to know how to explain it well also.

```
public class Enum {

public enum DictionaryFields {
    DistinctAdjective1("Distinct", "[adjective]", "Familiar. Worked in Java"),
    DistinctAdjective2("Distinct", "[adjective]", "Unique. No duplicates. Clearly different or of different kind."),
    DistinctAdverb("Distinct", "[adverb]", "Uniquely. Written \"distinctly\"."),
    DistinctNoun1("Distinct", "[noun]", "A keyword in this assignment."),
    DistinctNoun2("Distinct", "[noun]", "An advanced search option."),
    PlaceholderAdjective("Placeholder", "[adjective]", "To be updated...");


}

private final String generalNote = "DICTIONARY 340 JAVA";
private String definition;
private String word;
private String partOfSpeech;

private DictionaryFields(String word, String partOfSpeech, String definition) {
    this.word = word;
    this.partOfSpeech = partOfSpeech;
    this.definition = definition;
}

public String getWord() {
    return word;
}

public void setWord {
    this.word = word;
}

public String getPartOfSpeech() {
    return partOfSpeech;
}

public void setPartOfSpeech() {
    this.partOfSpeech = partOfSpeech;
}

public String getDefinition() {
    return definition;
}

public void setDefinition(String definition) {
    this.definition = definition;
}
```

}

Comment: Get rid of the very first line, and also the `}` character about 10 lines down.

Comment: create the enum in a separate file, don't compact all thing in one file, the error is mentioned by @DawoodibnKareem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some syntactical issues with your code. Specifically, you are defining a class called "Enum", but you should actually be defining an enum like:

```
public enum DictionaryFields {
    DistinctAdjective1("Distinct", "[adjective]", "Familiar. Worked in Java"),
    DistinctAdjective2("Distinct", "[adjective]", "Unique. No duplicates. Clearly different or of different kind."),
    DistinctAdverb("Distinct", "[adverb]", "Uniquely. Written \"distinctly\"."),
    DistinctNoun1("Distinct", "[noun]", "A keyword in this assignment."),
    DistinctNoun2("Distinct", "[noun]", "An advanced search option."),
    PlaceholderAdjective("Placeholder", "[adjective]", "To be updated...");



    private final String generalNote = "DICTIONARY 340 JAVA";
    private String definition;
    private String word;
    private String partOfSpeech;

    private DictionaryFields(String word, String partOfSpeech, String definition) {
        this.word = word;
        this.partOfSpeech = partOfSpeech;
        this.definition = definition;
    }

    public String getWord() {
        return word;
    }

    public void setWord() {
        this.word = word;
    }

    public String getPartOfSpeech() {
        return partOfSpeech;
    }

    public void setPartOfSpeech() {
        this.partOfSpeech = partOfSpeech;
    }

    public String getDefinition() {
        return definition;
    }

    public void setDefinition(String definition) {
        this.definition = definition;
    }

}
```

You needed to define the constructor inside "DictionaryFields". They way you had it setup was that you were actually defining a constructor for "Enum" class.

Comment: TLDR: you defined the constructor in the wrong place. You also didn't need a wrapper class called "Enum"

Answer (score 0):

Your enum’s constructor is not in the enum’s scope. The problem is same with the fields and the getters/setters. Move them into enum’s block and it will be fine.